# Effusion rate 1.4 times faster SO2(g)

Tags: gas-laws, kinetic-theory-of-gases

How do I solve this-
Which diatomic gas would effuse at a rate that is 1.4 times faster than the rate at which so2(g) effuses at any given temperature? This is high school chemistry.

I did: (using graham's law) 1.4= sqroot of 64g*mol-1 / xg*mol-1 => 1.96= 64/x => 1.96x=64 => x=32.65g/mol. 32.65/2 (bc its a diatom) => 16.325g/mol which is close to oxygen. 
At first, I found Urms of SO2 using 273k for T, 0.064kg for M and 8.314 for R, I got 326. Then multiplied that by 1.4 and got 456. Then I put 456/326= sqroot of 64g*mol-1/ xg*mol-1 and solved for x. I realized the 456/326 equaled 1.4, so I figured I didn't need to find Urms in the first place.

Comment: See Graham's law of effusion

Comment: would O2 be the correct answer?

Comment: This is a [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/141/7448) question. We have a policy which states that ‎you should show your thoughts and/or efforts into solving the problem. It'll make us certain that ‎we aren't doing your homework for you. Otherwise, this question may get closed.‎ Please [edit] in your full reasoning or thoughts on this.

Comment: @Chrissy we will tell you whether oxygen is correct if you tell us how you arrived at that possibility.

Comment: @OscarLanzi sorry didn't know about the policy. I updated the post.

Comment: @chrissy now it can be told, you're good.

Comment: The rate of effusion is proportional to the mean speed of the molecules which in turn is proportional to $ 1\sqrt{M}$ (at constant temperature).  From this and by using ratios you can work out what the M for the unknown is.